# Checking integrity of redux state on initialization

Tags: javascript, node.js, redux

I am using redux to keep the state of the view so when users come back they have the exact same view and settings they selected before, I do this emitting events to the server and replicating the changes in a store on the backend and storing the state on the database.

Every time a user logs in we get his settings using this cide:

```
if(!user.state){
            socket.store = redux.createStore(reducer);
        }else{
            socket.store = redux.createStore(reducer, user.state);
        }
```

The problem arises when I want to add new reducers for new features and the state saved on the database becomes outdated, when I try passing the old state object to the createStore function I get

```
[Error: Reducer "fooReducer" returned undefined during initialization. If the state passed to the reducer is undefined, you must explicitly return the initial state. The initial state may n
ot be undefined.
```

And my reducers:

```
//this is a new reducer
function fooReducer(state, action) {
    if (!state) {
        state = defaultState.foo
    }
    switch (action.type) {
    ...
        default:
            return state
    }

}

module.exports = combineReducers({
    theme: themeReducer,
    settings: settingsReducer,
    foo: fooReducer,
});
```

Shouldn't the reducer check for undefined state cover these escenarios? 
What would be the best practice to handle this and future scenarios when I want to add new reducers?

I am thinking to write a function to check if each key on the state is initialized but this seems like something the reducer should already be doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the problem was because I didn't set a value for foo in the default state

```
defaultState.foo = {x: 'var'}
```